# Modus bei Tatsachenwiedergabe im Referat

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech

Wenn ich mich in einem Referat von einer wiedergegebenen Aussage distanziere, kann ich Konjunktiv II verwenden:

> Ein Klassenkamerad behauptete immer, dass die Erde eine Scheibe *wäre*.

Wie ist es jedoch, wenn ich eine Tatsache wiedergebe – die ich selber für wahr halte – verwende ich dann Konjunktiv I oder Indikativ?

> Der Lehrer bestand darauf, dass die Erde (annähernd) eine Kugel *sei*.
>   Der Lehrer bestand darauf, dass die Erde (annähernd) eine Kugel *ist*.

Der Konjunktiv I markiert ja die gewisse Unsicherheit des Referats, andererseits ist die Erde unabhängig von dem, was der Lehrer sagte, (annähernd) eine Kugel.

Gibt es dafür eine Regel?

Answer (score 1):

Hier gibt es eigentlich kein eindeutiges Regelwerk, da die Sache sich wesentlich schwieriger gestaltet wenn der Kontext nicht mehr ganz so eindeutig ist.

Prinzipiell kann man festhalten, dass sowohl die referenzierte 3. Person eine Meinung zu seiner eigenen Aussage hat als auch der Referent (Du), der später über diese 3. Person eine Aussage macht.

Stell Dir die folgende Situation vor:

Es ist jetzt '*gestern*' und Hans ***denkt***, dass er gestern (also vom heutigen Standpunkt des Referenten aus gesehen '*vorgestern*') noch geglaubt habe/hat, die Welt sei/ist eine Scheibe. Dann spricht er seinen Gedanken aus und der Referent nimmt ihn zur Kenntnis.

Zurück in die Gegenwart - der Referent (Du) sagt:

> Referent: "***Hans hat mir gestern gesagt, dass er noch vorgestern geglaubt hätte/hatte/habe, die Welt ist/sei/wäre eine Scheibe.***"

Abgesehen davon welche Formen jetzt die wirklich richtigen sind ist Eines sonnenklar:

> ***'dass die Welt eine Scheibe ist/sei/wäre'***

wird eindeutig als die persönliche Meinung Hansens angesehen!

Kein Platz also um mit einer '*grammatikalischen Form*' die Meinung des Referenten einzubringen. Der Referent muss *ergänzen* oder *periphrasieren*...

---

Wenn dein Lehrer also ***behauptet***, dann sagt er wohl 'ist'! Somit ist auch deine Meinung im Konjunktiv des Referats sicher aufgehoben. Wenn der Lehrer aber nur mit 'sei/wäre' ***vermutet***, dann ist es nicht mehr klar ob der Konjunktiv des Referats sich auf *seine* oder *deine* persönliche Meinung bezieht, auch wenn du als Referent explizit sagen würdest: *'Mein Lehrer vermutet...'!*

Comment: Falls dieser Text eine Antwort enthält, hast Du sie gut versteckt.

Comment: @CarstenS: Dann lies einfach die ersten sieben Worte noch einmal...

Answer (score 1):

Je nachdem für wie wahr du die Aussage eigentlich hältst. Oder anders ausgedrückt: Wie angreifbar du dich bei einer Falschaussage machen möchtest.

Journalisten, wenn Sie Politiker wiedergeben verwenden grundsätzlich den Konjunktiv I; in der Regel sogar wenn das wiedergegebene eigentlich klar ist. Denn das alte Journalistenhandbuch legt nahe, sich niemals mit einer Sache gemein zu machen (auch nicht mit einer guten).

> Schäuble (bei der Einbringung des Haushaltsentwurfs): »Für dieses Projekt sind 15 Millionen Euro im Haushaltsentwurf eingeplant.«
>
> Zeitung: Für das Projekt seien 15 Millionen Euro eingeplant, so Finanzminister Schäuble bei der Haushaltsdebatte im Bundestag.

Die Zahl steht im Entwurf drin, der Entwurf wurde abgesegnet, die Zahl existiert; dennoch wird sich in der Regel ein indirektes Zitat im Konjunktiv I finden.

Erst wenn man sich sicher ist, dass man die Sache (auch) als seine eigene verkaufen möchte, sollte man den Indikativ wählen.